# Plotting classification decision boundary line based on perceptron coefficients

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning

This is practically a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023678/4089351). However, I want to ask a very specific question regarding plotting of the decision boundary line based on the perceptron coefficients I got with a rudimentary "manual" coding experiment. As you can see the coefficients extracted from a logistic regression result in a nice decision boundary line:

[image]

based on the `glm()` results:

```
(Intercept)       test1       test2 
   1.718449    4.012903    3.743903
```

The coefficients on the perceptron experiment are radically different:

```
     bias     test1     test2 
 9.131054 19.095881 20.736352
```

To facilitate an answer, [here is the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwl-HpVJ_5PecGxuWk9vR1pzWUk), and here is the code:

```
# DATA PRE-PROCESSING:
dat = read.csv("perceptron.txt", header=F)
dat[,1:2] = apply(dat[,1:2], MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) scale(x)) # scaling the data
data = data.frame(rep(1,nrow(dat)), dat) # introducing the "bias" column
colnames(data) = c("bias","test1","test2","y")
data$y[data$y==0] = -1 # Turning 0/1 dependent variable into -1/1.
data = as.matrix(data) # Turning data.frame into matrix to avoid mmult problems.

# PERCEPTRON:
set.seed(62416)
no.iter = 1000                           # Number of loops
theta = rnorm(ncol(data) - 1)            # Starting a random vector of coefficients.
theta = theta/sqrt(sum(theta^2))         # Normalizing the vector.
h = theta %*% t(data[,1:3])              # Performing the first f(theta^T X)

for (i in 1:no.iter){                    # We will recalculate 1,000 times
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)){               # Each time we go through each example.
      if(h[j] * data[j, 4] < 0){         # If the hypothesis disagrees with the sign of y,
      theta = theta + (sign(data[j,4]) * data[j, 1:3]) # We + or - the example from theta.
      }
      else
      theta = theta                      # Else we let it be.
  }
  h = theta %*% t(data[,1:3])            # Calculating h() after iteration.
}
theta                                    # Final coefficients
mean(sign(h) == data[,4])                # Accuracy
```

**QUESTION: How to plot the boundary line (as I did above using the logistic regression coefficients) if we only have the perceptron coefficients?**

Answer (score 0):

Well... It turns out that it is exactly the same as in the [case of logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38015736/4089351), and despite the widely different coefficients: pick the minimum and maximum of the abscissa (test 1), add a slight margin, and calculate the corresponding test 2 values at the decision boundary (when `0 = theta_o + theta_1 test1 + theta_2 test2`), and draw the line between the points:

```
palette(c("tan3","purple4"))
plot(test2 ~ test1, col = as.factor(y), pch = 20, data=data,
     main="College admissions")
(x = c(min(data[,2])-.2,  max(data[,2])+ .2))
(y = c((-1/theta[3]) * (theta[2] * x + theta[1])))
lines(x, y, lwd=3, col=rgb(.7,0,.2,.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Perceptron weights are calculated so that when theta^T X > 0, it classifies as positive, and when theta^T X < 0 it classifies as negative. This means the equation theta^T X is your decision boundary for the perceptron.

The same logic applies to logistic regression except its now sigmoid(theta^T X) > 0.5.

Comment: The usual threshold for for the sigmoid function is 0.5, which corresponds to the crossing through zero of Theta^T X.

Comment: You're right. I forgot the sigmoid goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: I think my question was very specific, and I left the answer as opposed to erasing the whole post, just in case someone else could benefit from it (in the interval, I have already seen similar questions).